# UIAlertController textfield not getting input

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to code, an `UIAlertController` that gets input from the user through a `UITextfield`.

When i run the print statement nothing gets printed after i type something in the textfield and hit the save button.

```
@IBAction func reqTimeButton(_ sender: Any) {

  // time is requested by student

    timer.invalidate()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time Request", message: "Please enter your reason to extend the time of your trip", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (reason) in

        reason.placeholder = "" }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        let textField = alert.textFields![0]
        textField.text = self.request
        self.totalTime = self.totalTime + 480
        self.initialTime = self.initialTime + 480
        self.runTimer()
        print(textField.text!)   }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        self.runTimer()  }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting whatever text is entered in the textfield when you do `textField.text = self.request`

Comment: what is the OP you expect, what the value you get in here `self.request`

Comment: i am trying to set the value i get to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the text from `UITextField`, I hope this helps you.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time Request", message: "Please enter your reason to extend the time of your trip", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your reason"
}
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: { (okAction) in
       let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
       print(textField)
}))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured out what was wrong. This is the working code.

@IBAction func reqTimeButton(_ sender: Any) {

```
  // time is requested by student

    timer.invalidate()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time Request", message: "Please enter your reason to extend the time of your trip", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (reason) in

        reason.placeholder = "" }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        let textField = alert.textFields![0]
        print(textField.text!)
        self.totalTime = self.totalTime + 480
        self.initialTime = self.initialTime + 480
        self.runTimer()
        self.request = textField.text!
        print(self.request)  }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        self.runTimer()  }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: thank you guys for pointing out that they variable was overwritten, ill make sure to be careful next time.